# VueJs and JHipster UAA returns 401 unauthorized

Tags: vue.js, jhipster

Hi I am trying to utilize JHipster with vue using uaa. UAA works completely with angular js. If I try vue js as the gateway with a UAA server I get a 401 unauthorized. Is the vuejs blueprint supported with UAA?

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe UAA auth has been implemented in the `jhipster-vuejs` blueprint, based on https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-vuejs/issues/448

Comment: Yep. Looks like you are correct. Hmmmm... May try to get it to work.